# Button activated when date picker and text field are set in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, button, datepicker

I want to implement a function that activates the button when the text field and date picker are set.

The value of the date picker goes to the label, and I checked the button by changing the label value.

However, among other functions that I have implemented, if the navigation is popped using a singleton object and the value is saved when it comes back, if the button is checked with a label change, the button is not activated because it is duplicated with the singleton, or even if only the phone number is set. It happens that the button is activated.

So, rather than changing the label, is there a way to catch it when the date picker itself changes the value?

```swift
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let date = DateFormatter()
        date.dateStyle = .medium
        date.timeStyle = .none
        return date
    }()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        numberTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        numberTextField.text = UserInformation.userInformationSingleton.userNumber
        dateLabel.text = UserInformation.userInformationSingleton.dateLabel
    }
    
    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text?.count == 1 {
            if textField.text?.first == " " {
                textField.text = ""
                return
            }
        }
        toggleButton()
    }
    
    func toggleButton() {
        guard
            let textField = numberTextField.text, !textField.isEmpty,
            dateLabel.text != ""
            else {
                signUpButton.isEnabled = false
                return
        }
        signUpButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    
    @IBAction func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        toggleButton()
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        UserInformation.userInformationSingleton.userID = nil
        UserInformation.userInformationSingleton.userNumber = nil
        UserInformation.userInformationSingleton.dateLabel = nil
    }
    
    @IBAction func tappedPreviousButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func tappedSignUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1GVc.png

thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem!

```swift
func toggleButton() {
        guard
            let textField = numberTextField.text, !textField.isEmpty,
            let label = dateLabel.text, !label.isEmpty
            else {
                signUpButton.isEnabled = false
                return
        }
        signUpButton.isEnabled = true
    }
```